# MS SQL to SQLite syntax

Tags: sql, sql-server, sqlite

First of all, I'm trying to achieve the following:
[image]

I first used MS SQL to figure out how I'm Able to align the tags together.

Here is the schema if you would like to recreate the unnormalised table.

```
CREATE TABLE unnormalized(
  vendor_tag varchar(200),
  vendor_tag_name varchar(200),
  vendor_id int
  );
  
 INSERT INTO unnormalized
VALUES
('5,8,30,24','Burgers,Desserts,Fries,Salads',1),
('5','Burgers',2),
('8,42','Desserts,Mexican',3),
('1,5,30,16','American,Burgers,Fries,Sandwiches',4),
('1,5,30,16','American,Burgers,Fries,Sandwiches',5);
```

Here is the code for the normalised  table

```
SELECT
    --*
    DISTINCT CAST(tag_id AS INT) as tag_id ,tag_name
FROM unnormalized 
CROSS APPLY 
(
    (SELECT 
        value as tag_id,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(vendor_tag,',') 
    ) a1
    INNER JOIN 
    (SELECT 
        value as tag_name,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS rn
     FROM STRING_SPLIT(vendor_tag_name,',') 
     ) a2
    ON a1.rn = a2.rn
) 
ORDER BY tag_id
```

Now I'm trying to rewrite this code using SQLite. However there are a few differences such as 'CROSS APPLY' and 'STRING_SPLIT' not being in SQLite. I've looked around and I found out that CROSS APPLY is maybe similar to 'CROSS JOIN' in SQLite and maybe using something like this to separate the string at the first comma it finds??

```
WITH split(vendor_id, vendor_tag, str) AS (
    SELECT vendor_id, '', vendor_tag||',' FROM unnormalized
    UNION ALL SELECT vendor_id,
    substr(str, 0, instr(str, ',')),
    substr(str, instr(str, ',')+1)
    FROM split 
    WHERE str
) 

SELECT vendor_id, vendor_tag
FROM split 
WHERE vendor_tag
ORDER BY vendor_id;
```

Comment: Fix your data model!  Don't store multiple values in a single column!  Don't store numbers as strings!

Comment: This table isn't just "unnormalized", it fails the most basic design rule - each cell should contain an *atomic* value. If you used a proper schema you wouldn't have any problems. Even in databases that have arrays, there's *no* relation between the elements of different arrays

Comment: As for SQLite, you gain nothing at all by splitting the values in SQL. SQLite is an *embedded* database, which means the engine is hosted and run by your application, using your application's RAM. It's a lot faster to split the strings in your client application's language than try to do the same in SQLite

Comment: @Panagiotis Kanavos The table is data from a csv file that I found in kaggle and was doing some exercises to populate the data into a database

Comment: Why did you use such a schema? What problem were you trying to fix? Not speed or scaleability - this schema is extremely slow and doesn't scale at all. Each query has to scan the entire table and can't use any indexes. Space? This is probably using *more* space than a proper table with integer IDs, even for a small number of vendors. If you have lots of vendors, you can use table compression in SQL Server

Comment: @Q.T CSV files don't have multiple values per cell either. You should clean up the data *before* inserting it to the database. It's far easier to use `String.Split` in C# to process rows one at a time than it is to fix the data once it's inside the database

Comment: The dataset looked pretty messy but also looked easier enough to normalise. The table I showed is the only part that I’m struggling to normalise thought I could somehow separate them

Comment: I was going to clean both columns using pandas in python but wanted to ask if it was somehow possible in SQLite first

Comment: The string_split function in tsql does not preserve order, which you tried to kludge around using `OVER(ORDER BY (SELECT NULL))`. So your tsql "solution" is not logically correct and will fail (i.e., compute inconsistent row numbers) at some undetermined point in the future. The correct tsql solution is to use a splitting function that does maintain order and provides it for your joining needs.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In SQLite you can do it with a recursive CTE:

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT 
    vendor_tag, 
    vendor_tag_name,
    SUBSTR(vendor_tag, 1, INSTR(vendor_tag || ',', ',') - 1) col1,
    SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, 1, INSTR(vendor_tag_name || ',', ',') - 1) col2
  FROM unnormalized 
  UNION ALL 
  SELECT 
    SUBSTR(vendor_tag, LENGTH(col1) + 2), 
    SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, LENGTH(col2) + 2), 
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag, LENGTH(col1) + 2), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag, LENGTH(col1) + 2) || ',', ',') - 1),
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, LENGTH(col2) + 2), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, LENGTH(col2) + 2) || ',', ',') - 1)
  FROM cte  
  WHERE LENGTH(vendor_tag) AND LENGTH(vendor_tag_name)
)
SELECT DISTINCT col1 vendor_tag, col2 vendor_tag_name
FROM cte
WHERE NOT (INSTR(col1, ',') OR INSTR(col2, ',')) AND (LENGTH(col1) AND LENGTH(col2))
ORDER BY vendor_tag + 0
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=6c758a146339b7aa6f64dc1c10efb09c).
Results:

```
> vendor_tag | vendor_tag_name
> :--------- | :--------------
> 1          | American       
> 5          | Burgers        
> 8          | Desserts       
> 16         | Sandwiches     
> 24         | Salads         
> 30         | Fries          
> 42         | Mexican
```

Comment: Wow this works, thank you!!  I haven't looked a lot into recursive CTE at the moment, and I'm slightly struggling in reading the code. But i'll study the code a bit further!

Comment: ```SUBSTR(vendor_tag, LENGTH(col1) + 2), 
    SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, LENGTH(col2) + 2), 
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag, LENGTH(col1) + 2), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag, LENGTH(col1) + 2) || ',', ',') - 1),
    SUBSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, LENGTH(col2) + 2), 1, INSTR(SUBSTR(vendor_tag_name, LENGTH(col2) + 2) || ',', ',') - 1)  ``` Could you give a little more insight in this part of the code?

Comment: @Q.T A recursive CTE is actually a loop (something like a while loop in other programming languages). In every iteration I get the part of the string up the first `,` and in the next iteration I get the part of the remaining string up to the next `,` and so on. This is why I use string functions like INSTR(), SUBSTR().

Comment: Hi another question. How would I use that code to insert it into this table? ```CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS tag (
    tag_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY,
    tag_name TEXT,
); ```

Comment: @Q.T check this: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=11cc36c65ef83f117ed41cab07a8e4f0

Comment: Can I just say how brilliantly well you used recursive CTE here. Also nice use of INSTR to search for 1st comma appearance which naturally handles the added comma for strings without comma separators. I don’t understand why WHERE NOT (INSTR(col1, ',') OR INSTR(col2, ',')) was added. It makes no difference? At the end of the recursions, every cell must have been split by it’s commas and non comma strings extracted, there is no way for any comma left existing in the col1 and col2 columns.

Comment: It would make more sense to do WHERE NOT (INSTR(vendor_tag, ',') OR INSTR(vendor_tag_name, ',')) applying on 1st two columns instead since those are the ones that may have commas in them, except the rows from each starting row’s 2nd last recursion level (which should contain only 1 number/word) before reaching the last recursion returning empty string.

Comment: @Q.T Nice catch, you are right, `NOT (INSTR(col1, ',') OR INSTR(col2, ','))` is not needed. Maybe I initially put it there while testing (I don't remember). I tested again even with inconsistent data. I agree that it can be removed.